# Passing parameters from master pipeline to a SP activity in child pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to pass parameters from a Master pipeline to a stored proc activity in the Child pipeline using ExecutePipeline activity.

I've tried referencing the parameters as below but it throws an error-

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as a parameter while calling the execute pipeline activity for the child pipeline.

[image: Pipeline]

Expand the advanced section header under settings in the Execute Pipeline Activity for the child and add the required inputs.

Don't forget to create the parameters in the child pipeline first.

After passing the paramters from the master, you should be able to reference it while calling the stored procedure activity.

```
@pipeline().parameters.version
```

Comment: Thanks much.I actually tried all the above steps except the last one where I was trying to refer the parameters by passing the name of the Master pipeline which was not required. It works now :)